# iOS Cordova Media Plugin in background: MEDIA_ERR_NONE_SUPPORTED = 4

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

When running my app in background, I would get `MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_NONE_SUPPORTED (4)` when trying to create and play an audio file.

While most suggestions for this error relates to file format, file existence or audio recording, my audio files were playing perfectly when the app was in foreground.

Note: I am already using the **Cordova Background Mode** plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the **Cordova Music Controls** is causing this interference.

Without manipulating the music controls, audio plays perfectly even when the app enters background.

The problem came from **destroying the music controls**, which makes iOS prevent your app from playing audio until the user resumes the app to foreground.

Turns out you *don't* have to destroy music controls before creating them again, to update the track label.

TLDR; Don't kill music controls while playing audio in the background.

Comment: How did you destroy the music controls?